# Why is the cursor type adOpenForwardOnly's performance better than adOpenStatic?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb, database-cursor

I am trying to understand the difference between `CursorTypeEnum` 0 and 3, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681771(v=vs.85).aspx). Both are static, except type 0 only supports forward iteration.

In my case `rs.Open strsql, cn, 0` returns consistently in under 30 seconds, whereas performance of the same query with type 3 cursor fluctuates widely between 3 and 8 minutes.

They both need to lock the underlying tables in order to create static set, so why such dramatic difference?

*Disclaimer: I am no expert in VBA or transactional databases. I understand concurrency, algorithmic complexity, and data structures.*

Comment: Not an answer, but you should get into the habit of using `ADODB.Command` and `ADODB.Parameter` objects - that way you're not concatenating user input into your `strsql` (which is a serious security issue), and `Command.Execute` gives you an `ADODB.Recordset` for you to iterate... and then you don't need to worry about cursor types at all. Interesting and useful question nonetheless.

Comment: What do you actually **need** to do with the recordset?

Comment: I'm not sure any DB locking is required (it would help if you specified what database you're using).  How large is your recordset?  Seems like the results may not be unexpected though, maybe only the size of the difference.  There may be a lot more "work" involved in creating a arbitrarily-navigable recordset (3) vs. one which just supports moving forward.  What are the performance numbers if you navigate through to the end of each type (ie not just to time to return the first record) ?

Comment: I am not sure either. SQL Server. 5000 records, 200 columns.

Comment: Also, what did you set your cursor location property as? adUseClient or adUseServer? See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676564(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Without actually seeing the query, this is impossible to answer definitively, but I don't believe the difference is primarily caused by the cursor type. One very common gotcha is that varying the options under which the query executes (including but not limited to cursor types) can also result in the use of a different (cached) execution plan which may not be appropriate for the parameter values. Execute the query with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to see if that might be the issue.

Comment: The difference is due to, and only due to the cursor type. I benchmarked with type 3, then with type 0 with the same data and no other changes whatsoever.

Comment: Humor me. Try `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on your query anyway.